# Error while configuring Apache Zeppelin on Windows 10

Tags: hadoop, apache-zeppelin

I get the following error while trying to install and configure Apache Zeppelin on Windows 10:

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: The filename, 
directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.start(RemoteInterpreterManagedProcess.java:143)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.reference(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:73)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:265)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:430)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getFormType(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:111)
at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:387)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:329)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I followed below steps:
1. Downloaded and extracted folder to some location.
2. Download Java and set JAVA_HOME
3. Downloaded hadoop and set HADOOP_HOME
4. Ran zeppelin.cmd from bin folder
5. Opened zeppelin in a browser and ran example code.

Comment: Not clear what interpreter you're running, but if it's Spark, you also need to download it.

Comment: Finally after 3 days i was able to get zeppelin to work. Checkout my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52320063/1276846

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a whole day trying to get Zeppelin to work on Windows 10, so I know the pain. I'll outline the steps I took so you might see what went wrong with yours:

My environment: Windows 10 with latest updates. No Spark or Hadoop installed. Java 8.

- Download zeppelin binary from https://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html and extract it somewhere you like (I have Zeppelin 0.7.3 with all-interpreters)
- Make sure you have a java jdk installed and that you have JAVA_HOME set correctly (mine is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162)
- Create a folder for putting Hadoop stuff (e.g. C:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.8.1)
- Set the HADOOP_HOME environment variable to the above folder
- Get the Hadoop binaries for windows. These can be obtained from https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils. Extract them into a 'bin' folder inside your HADOOP_HOME (I have a folder C:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.8.1\bin with the binaries inside the 'bin')
- Run zeppelin.cmd
- Connect to localhost:8080 from your browser

I was having trouble because the Zeppelin page never mentions that you need to have a HADOOP_HOME and the winutils.exe binary. Relevant Zeppelin JIRA issue in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2438.

The above steps worked for me but I might have missed a couple things, so if anyone tries this and it doesn't work feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It took me hours to get it working, too. Setting JAVA_HOME was one step, but another I found in some places was to unzip the two war files to these directories.

C:\Users%USERNAME%\Downloads\zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all\zeppelin-web\dist
C:\Users%USERNAME%\Downloads\zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all\zeppelin-web-angular\dist

...and then I moved (or you could delete) the two war files elsewhere. I thought Jetty should do this deployment automatically, but for me it didn't.

See this for better instructions:
[Apache Zeppelin not loading in a browser in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078714/apache-zeppelin-not-loading-in-a-browser-in-windows-10)

[Edit] "Running" is arguable. I can't run cells. I get:
Could not delete "file:///C:/[...]/zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all/notebook/Python Tutorial/1. IPython Basic_2EYDJKFFY.zpln".

I am getting the impression that Zeppelin is not tested on Windows (most instructions recommend Docker or WSL.) (Linux can delete open files, and Windows cannot.)