# Apache Zeppelin not loading in a browser in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, apache-zeppelin

I followed the steps mentioned here https://gist.github.com/codspire/7b0955b9e67fe73f6118dad9539cbaa2

When entered "localhost:8080" in a browser nothing happens

Hadoop version -- 3.1.3

Spark version -- 3.0.0-preview pre-built for hadoop2.7

Zeppelin version -- 0.9.0-preview1

```
    C:\Zeppelin>bin\zeppelin.cmd                                                                                                                                                                           
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0                                                                                                 
    WARN [2020-04-07 16:29:59,113] ({main}ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:159) - Failed to load configuration, proceeding with a default                                                               
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,177] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:171) - Server Host: 127.0.0.1                                                                                                
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,177] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:173) - Server Port: 8080                                                                                                     
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,178] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:177) - Context Path: /                                                                                                       
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,178] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:178) - Zeppelin Version: 0.9.0-preview1                                                                                      
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,205] ({main} Log.java[initialized]:193) - Logging initialized @810ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog                                                                  
    WARN [2020-04-07 16:29:59,516] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[getConfigFSDir]:631) - zeppelin.config.fs.dir is not specified, fall back to local conf directory zeppelin.conf.dir                  
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,554] ({main} Credentials.java[loadFromFile]:121) - C:\Zeppelin\conf\credentials.json                                                                                         
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,594] ({ImmediateThread-1586257199511} PluginManager.java[loadNotebookRepo]:60) - Loading NotebookRepo Plugin: org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GitNotebookRepo
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,658] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[setupWebAppContext]:488) - warPath is: C:\Zeppelin\zeppelin-web-angular-0.9.0-preview1.war                                                  
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,659] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[setupWebAppContext]:501) - ZeppelinServer Webapp path: C:\Zeppelin\webapps                                                                  
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,729] ({ImmediateThread-1586257199511} VFSNotebookRepo.java[setNotebookDirectory]:70) - Using notebookDir: C:\Zeppelin\notebook                                               
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,746] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[setupWebAppContext]:488) - warPath is: zeppelin-web-angular/dist                                                                            
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,747] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[setupWebAppContext]:501) - ZeppelinServer Webapp path: C:\Zeppelin\webapps\next                                                             
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,811] ({main} NotebookServer.java[<init>]:153) - NotebookServer instantiated: org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer@683dbc2c                                              
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,812] ({main} NotebookServer.java[setServiceLocator]:158) - Injected ServiceLocator: ServiceLocatorImpl(shared-locator,0,246550802)                                           
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,814] ({main} NotebookServer.java[setAuthorizationServiceProvider]:178) - Injected NotebookAuthorizationServiceProvider                                                       
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,814] ({main} NotebookServer.java[setNotebookService]:171) - Injected NotebookServiceProvider                                                                                 
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,814] ({main} NotebookServer.java[setConnectionManagerProvider]:184) - Injected ConnectionManagerProvider                                                                     
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,815] ({main} NotebookServer.java[setNotebook]:164) - Injected NotebookProvider                                                                                               
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,816] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[setupClusterManagerServer]:439) - Cluster mode is disabled                                                                                  
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,827] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:251) - Starting zeppelin server                                                                                                       
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,829] ({main} Server.java[doStart]:370) - jetty-9.4.18.v20190429; built: 2019-04-29T20:42:08.989Z; git: e1bc35120a6617ee3df052294e433f3a25ce7097; jvm 1.8.0_241-b07           
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,858] ({ImmediateThread-1586257199511} GitNotebookRepo.java[init]:77) - Opening a git repo at '/C:/Zeppelin/notebook'                                                         
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,967] ({main} StandardDescriptorProcessor.java[visitServlet]:283) - NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet                                  
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,982] ({main} DefaultSessionIdManager.java[doStart]:365) - DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0                                                                         
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,982] ({main} DefaultSessionIdManager.java[doStart]:370) - No SessionScavenger set, using defaults                                                                            
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:29:59,985] ({main} HouseKeeper.java[startScavenging]:149) - node0 Scavenging every 600000ms                                                                                        
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:30:02,046] ({main} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:855) - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6150c3ec{zeppelin-web-angular,/,jar:file:///C:/Zeppelin/zeppelin-web-angular-0.9.0-preview1.war!/,AVAILABLE}{C:\Zeppelin\zeppelin-web-angular-0.9.0-preview1.war}                                                                                                                                    
    WARN [2020-04-07 16:30:02,051] ({main} WebInfConfiguration.java[unpack]:675) - Web application not found C:\Zeppelin\zeppelin-web-angular\dist                                                         
    WARN [2020-04-07 16:30:02,052] ({main} WebAppContext.java[doStart]:554) - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@229f66ed{/next,null,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\Zeppelin\zeppelin-web-angular\dist}     
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Zeppelin\zeppelin-web-angular\dist
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.unpack(WebInfConfiguration.java:676)                                                                                                                   
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:152)                                                                                                             
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:506)                                                                                                                         
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:544)                                                                                                                              
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)                                                                                                                 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)                                                                                                              
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)                                                                                                            
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)                                                                                                                  
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)                                                                                                                 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)                                                                                                              
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)                                                                                                                                              
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)                                                                                                            
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)                                                                                                                  
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)                                                                                                                                            
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)                                                                                                                 
        at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:253)                                                                                                                      
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:30:02,906] ({main} AbstractConnector.java[doStart]:292) - Started ServerConnector@4493d195{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{127.0.0.1:8080}                                                    
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:30:02,906] ({main} Server.java[doStart]:410) - Started @4519ms                                                                                                                     
    INFO [2020-04-07 16:30:07,924] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:265) - Done, zeppelin server started
```

Comment: Go for the stable version - https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/zeppelin/zeppelin-0.8.2/zeppelin-0.8.2-bin-all.tgz

Answer (score 6):

To install Zeppelin 9.0 on Windows 10:

1. Unzip the wan folders (with Winrar) into `bin/zeppelin-web-angular/dist` and `bin/zeppelin-web/dist`.
2. Then modify the config file `shiro.ini` to change the `user` and `pass` (The default are `admin` and `password1`)

Comment: This worked for me, with zeppelin version 9.0 preview.  For clarity, I unzipped "zeppelin-web-0.9.0-preview1.war" into the new directory ..\zeppelin-0.9.0-preview1-bin-all\zeppelin-web\dist\, and "zeppelin-web-angular-0.9.0-preview1.war" into the new directory ..\zeppelin-0.9.0-preview1-bin-all\zeppelin-web-angular\dist\.  I then deleted the two .war files.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. Although I actually had to put zeppelin-web-angular and zeppelin-web in the Users directory. Why they can't make this clear on the website I will never know.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly this workaround might help. "**zeppelin-web-angular-0.9.0-preview1.war**" comes along with the package as shown in below image, create required folders and then unzip the content. Post restarting the server, the web pages should be available.

[image]

[image]

Following links will be also useful to setup Zeppelin for windows 10,
https://gist.github.com/codspire/7b0955b9e67fe73f6118dad9539cbaa2
https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/apache-zeppelin-installation-on-windows-10/

Comment: I moved the 2 files you mentioned. but I got an error like this, did you encounter this, I opened a title for it. Where did the files appearing in the second photo come from? I have never seen them before.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62470572/http-error-503-on-localhost-zeppelin-9-0-windows

Comment: The directory shown in second photo is where the the zepellin reported the error for me, hence i did created the necessary folder and content for zepellin. Please check your case and place it as per reported in error message.

Answer (score 2):

I also tried with Zepplin 0.9.0 on windows 10. working fine.

1. Go to bin -> mkdir -p zeppelin-web-angular/dist and mkdir -p zeppelin-web/dist
2. Copy zeppelin-web-angular-0.9.0-preview2.war and zeppelin-web-0.9.0-preview2.war into dist folder respectively
3. unzip it
4. remove war files from dist folder
5. start Zepplin.cmd

Answer (score 1):

I observed the same issue with v0.10.0.
I followed the below steps and it worked.

1. Create `dist` directories at home path (e.g., `D:\Zeppline\zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all\zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all`) as below ->
   `mkdir -p zeppelin-web-angular/dist` and `mkdir -p zeppelin-web/dist`
2. Copy `zeppelin-web-angular-0.10.1.war` and `zeppelin-web-0.10.1.war` into the corresponding `dist` folders.
3. unzip the war file in each `dist` folder
4. remove the war files from the `dist` folders
5. start `zeppelin.cmd`

[Updated contents of zeppelin-0.10.1-bin-all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoAZ6.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. I posted same query on official website of zeppelin on which some one replied that zeppelin is not supported on window 10.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-4749?filter=-2

I tried with 0.9, 0.8, 0.7 version of zeppelin, none of them working[on window 10] and show same blank url on localhost:8080. But recently now I have downloaded 0.6.2 version to find that this version is running fine. So I think we have to work on lower version of zeppelin or if you are using ubuntu all the version will run fine.

Comment: Thanks, If it wont run on windows 10, why is the cmd files there in the bin folder??

Comment: Even I don't know. May be they have kept for enterprise level. I have home and pro version of window 10 and I have checked on both pc's to confirm this.

Comment: anyways, I tried 0.6.2 version on my windows 10 Home, and it DIDNT work, bad luck. Now I am using on Ubuntu on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this version http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/zeppelin/zeppelin-0.8.1/zeppelin-0.8.1-bin-netinst.tgz  and it successful

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `ZEPPELIN_ANGULAR_WAR` env variable to location of war file. E.g.
`c:\zeppelin-home\zeppelin-web-angular-0.10.1.war`

Answer (score -1):

The current answer by the developers is that zeppelin 0.9 will not work on windows 10.

On windows 10, you can run zeppelin 0.9 in a docker container as a workaround

Refer to the instructions on this page 
http://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html

If you have docker installed, use this command to launch Apache Zeppelin in a container.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.9.0
```