# Apache Zeppelin will not start

Tags: windows-10, apache-zeppelin, logfile

Newbie here, please be gentle.

The computer in question uses Windows 10 and Apache Zeppelin(zeppelin-0.9.0-bin-all.tgz) refuses to start.

I've tried removing .template from the config files and still nothing.

It doesn't pass the line: INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,310] ({main} LuceneSearch.java[]:93) - Use C:\Zeppelin\tmp\zeppelin-index for storing lucene search index.

Not entirely sure what to do at this point, tried the solutions here: [Apache Zeppelin not loading in a browser in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61078714/apache-zeppelin-not-loading-in-a-browser-in-windows-10) and here: https://gist.github.com/codspire/7b0955b9e67fe73f6118dad9539cbaa2 and I just cannot figure out what is wrong.

Of note, I have Spark (spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz) installed separately and it seems to work even though it throws this warning: 21/01/29 18:16:39 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped

ANY suggestions would be greatly appreciated because I'm not sure what else to try.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.746]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>zeppelin.cmd
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:18,140] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:172) - Load configuration from file:/C:/Zeppelin/conf/zeppelin-site.xml
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:18,229] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:180) - Server Host: 127.0.0.1
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:18,229] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:182) - Server Port: 8080
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:18,229] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:186) - Context Path: /
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:18,229] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:187) - Zeppelin Version: 0.9.0
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:18,258] ({main} Log.java[initialized]:169) - Logging initialized @811ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
 WARN [2021-01-29 17:46:18,682] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[getConfigFSDir]:694) - zeppelin.config.fs.dir is not specified, fall back to local conf directory zeppelin.conf.dir
 WARN [2021-01-29 17:46:18,682] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[getConfigFSDir]:694) - zeppelin.config.fs.dir is not specified, fall back to local conf directory zeppelin.conf.dir
 WARN [2021-01-29 17:46:18,683] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[getConfigFSDir]:694) - zeppelin.config.fs.dir is not specified, fall back to local conf directory zeppelin.conf.dir
 WARN [2021-01-29 17:46:18,722] ({main} LocalConfigStorage.java[loadCredentials]:88) - Credential file C:\Zeppelin\conf\credentials.json is not existed
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:18,782] ({ImmediateThread-1611960378676} PluginManager.java[loadNotebookRepo]:78) - Loading NotebookRepo Plugin: org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GitNotebookRepo
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:18,948] ({ImmediateThread-1611960378676} VFSNotebookRepo.java[setNotebookDirectory]:69) - Using notebookDir: C:\Zeppelin\notebook
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:18,957] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[setupWebAppContext]:575) - warPath is: C:\Zeppelin\zeppelin-web-angular-0.9.0.war
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:18,975] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[setupWebAppContext]:588) - ZeppelinServer Webapp path: C:\Zeppelin\webapps
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,016] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[setupWebAppContext]:575) - warPath is: zeppelin-web-angular/dist
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,016] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[setupWebAppContext]:588) - ZeppelinServer Webapp path: C:\Zeppelin\webapps\next
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,051] ({ImmediateThread-1611960378676} GitNotebookRepo.java[init]:77) - Opening a git repo at '/C:/Zeppelin/notebook'
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,111] ({main} NotebookServer.java[<init>]:157) - NotebookServer instantiated: org.apache.zeppelin.socket.NotebookServer@1b2abca6
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,112] ({main} NotebookServer.java[setNotebook]:168) - Injected NotebookProvider
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,114] ({main} NotebookServer.java[setNotebookService]:175) - Injected NotebookServiceProvider
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,115] ({main} NotebookServer.java[setAuthorizationServiceProvider]:182) - Injected NotebookAuthorizationServiceProvider
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,115] ({main} NotebookServer.java[setConnectionManagerProvider]:188) - Injected ConnectionManagerProvider
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,116] ({main} NotebookServer.java[setServiceLocator]:162) - Injected ServiceLocator: ServiceLocatorImpl(shared-locator,0,891095110)
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,118] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[setupClusterManagerServer]:465) - Cluster mode is disabled
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,118] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:249) - Starting zeppelin server
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,121] ({main} Server.java[doStart]:360) - jetty-9.4.31.v20200723; built: 2020-07-23T17:57:36.812Z; git: 450ba27947e13e66baa8cd1ce7e85a4461cacc1d; jvm 1.8.0_281-b09
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,288] ({main} StandardDescriptorProcessor.java[visitServlet]:276) - NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,309] ({main} DefaultSessionIdManager.java[doStart]:334) - DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,310] ({main} DefaultSessionIdManager.java[doStart]:339) - No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,313] ({main} HouseKeeper.java[startScavenging]:140) - node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,327] ({main} ContextHandler.java[log]:2303) - Initializing Shiro environment
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:19,327] ({main} EnvironmentLoader.java[initEnvironment]:133) - Starting Shiro environment initialization.
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:21,130] ({main} EnvironmentLoader.java[initEnvironment]:147) - Shiro environment initialized in 1802 ms.
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:23,071] ({main} ContextHandler.java[doStart]:860) - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4a668b6e{zeppelin-web-angular,/,jar:file:///C:/Zeppelin/zeppelin-web-angular-0.9.0.war!/,AVAILABLE}{C:\Zeppelin\zeppelin-web-angular-0.9.0.war}
 WARN [2021-01-29 17:46:23,083] ({main} WebInfConfiguration.java[unpack]:662) - Web application not found C:\WINDOWS\system32\zeppelin-web-angular\dist
 WARN [2021-01-29 17:46:23,085] ({main} WebAppContext.java[doStart]:533) - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4e268090{/next,null,UNAVAILABLE}{C:\WINDOWS\system32\zeppelin-web-angular\dist}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\WINDOWS\system32\zeppelin-web-angular\dist
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.unpack(WebInfConfiguration.java:663)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:488)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:523)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.jetty.TimedHandler.doStart(TimedHandler.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:408)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:251)
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:23,119] ({main} AbstractConnector.java[doStart]:331) - Started ServerConnector@7ce6a65d{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{127.0.0.1:8080}
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:23,120] ({main} Server.java[doStart]:400) - Started @5677ms
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,129] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:263) - Done, zeppelin server started
 WARN [2021-01-29 17:46:28,151] ({main} VFSNotebookRepo.java[listFolder]:107) - Skip hidden folder: /Zeppelin/notebook/.git
 WARN [2021-01-29 17:46:28,154] ({main} LocalConfigStorage.java[loadNotebookAuthorization]:77) - NotebookAuthorization file C:\Zeppelin\conf\notebook-authorization.json is not existed
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,369] ({Thread-12} RemoteInterpreterEventServer.java[run]:105) - InterpreterEventServer is starting at 192.168.0.3:55104
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,870] ({main} RemoteInterpreterEventServer.java[start]:133) - RemoteInterpreterEventServer is started
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,880] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[<init>]:197) - Using RecoveryStorage: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.recovery.NullRecoveryStorage
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,929] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: alluxio
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,932] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: angular
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,936] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: beam
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,941] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: bigquery
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,947] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: cassandra
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,950] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: elasticsearch
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,954] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: file
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,959] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: flink
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,962] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: geode
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,964] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: groovy
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,966] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: hazelcastjet
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,969] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: hbase
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,971] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: ignite
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,975] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: influxdb
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,977] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: java
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,980] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: jdbc
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,985] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: jupyter
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,988] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: kotlin
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,993] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: ksql
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,996] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: kylin
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:28,999] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: lens
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,004] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: livy
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,010] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: md
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,015] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: mongodb
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,019] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: neo4j
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,020] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: pig
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,024] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: python
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,027] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: r
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,030] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: sap
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,033] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: scalding
 WARN [2021-01-29 17:46:29,069] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadInterpreterSettingFromDefaultDir]:437) - No interpreter-setting.json found in C:\Zeppelin\interpreter\scio
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,071] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: sh
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,078] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: spark
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,081] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: sparql
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,084] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterSetting]:540) - Register InterpreterSettingTemplate: submarine
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,086] ({main} LocalConfigStorage.java[loadInterpreterSettings]:63) - Load Interpreter Setting from file: C:\Zeppelin\conf\interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,175] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting beam from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,177] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting ignite from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,177] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting geode from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,178] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting jdbc from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,179] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting influxdb from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,180] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting lens from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,180] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting pig from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,181] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting file from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,182] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting java from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,183] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting jupyter from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,183] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting elasticsearch from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,184] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting submarine from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,185] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting sh from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,186] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting spark from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,187] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting md from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,187] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting hazelcastjet from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,188] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting alluxio from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,189] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting bigquery from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,190] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting mongodb from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,192] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting hbase from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,192] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting python from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,193] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting sap from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,194] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting kotlin from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,194] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting scalding from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,195] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting flink from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,196] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting angular from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,196] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting ksql from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,197] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting livy from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,197] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting r from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,198] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting groovy from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,199] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting neo4j from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,203] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting cassandra from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,204] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting sparql from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,205] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[loadFromFile]:294) - Create interpreter setting kylin from interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,211] ({main} LocalConfigStorage.java[save]:53) - Save Interpreter Setting to C:\Zeppelin\conf\interpreter.json
 INFO [2021-01-29 17:46:29,310] ({main} LuceneSearch.java[<init>]:93) - Use C:\Zeppelin\tmp\zeppelin-index for storing lucene search index
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you stop running Zeppelin under Windows. Besides that old versions (like 0.8.0) had Windows in the README, the new version of Zeppelin - 0.9.0 - doesn't even mention Windows in the list of supported platforms.

As far as I understand, the Zeppelin team is not as large to provide Windows support, and you will encounter a lot of bugs, and the only one who can fix it is you.

In ancient times, messengers who delivered bad news were killed. I hope something has changed since then!

You can try to run Zeppelin under Docker, WSL2, or inside the full virtual machine with Linux inside.

The easiest way to run Zeppelin in Windows is to install [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/), and then run something like `docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.9.0`

[image]